# Repeatable Flyway Migration

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, flyway

How do I achieve repeateable migration of sql scripts to every database? I have a segment called API and this need to be deployed in all the existing databases in sql server.
Though I am able to repeatedly run/execute the set of scripts based on the naming convention, not able to run on every dbs.

As of now, I have a data-system.json file where all the dbs and segments are registered and I am using this to run the particular segment of a single db.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you're asking, but in reference to the first part of your question:

> How do I achieve repeateable migration of sql scripts to every database?

If you want to to run your Flyway scripts on multiple databases, you can use the 'migrate' command in the Flyway CLI to do that (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/migrate). 
You can configure the environment specific info (e.g. login credentials) using environment variables (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/envvars).

Thanks